# CIDetector either not detecting, or detecting in odd places

Tags: ios, swift, image-recognition, cidetector

I am practicing using some swift 2 and have run in to some difficulties in using the CIDetector.

I have an app which has a series of pictures in; three different rectangles and three different photos of people/groups. I have been just trying the CIDetector on these images to see what is recognised. The most success I have has is with the faces - however the face it's recognising are in very weird places on the image.

Here is a rectangle image I tested, along with it's output:
[image: Rectangle Test]

And here is a face image:
[image]

Here is my detection code:

```
    ///does the detecting of features
        func detectFeatures() -> [CIFeature]? {

            print("detecting")

            let detectorOptions: [String: AnyObject] = [CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh, CIDetectorImageOrientation: 6]
            var detectorType    : String

            switch currentPhoto.currentType {
            case .RECTANGLES:
                detectorType = CIDetectorTypeRectangle
            case .FACES:
                detectorType = CIDetectorTypeFace
            default:
                print("error in phototype")
                return nil

            }

            let detector = CIDetector(ofType: detectorType, context: nil, options: detectorOptions)
            let image = CIImage(image: imageViewer.image!)

            guard image != nil else{
                print("image not cast to CIImage")
                return nil
            }

            return detector.featuresInImage(image!)
        }
```

Where the stars are added on:

```
for f in features!{
            print(f.bounds.origin)
            imageViewer.layer.addSublayer(createMarker(f.bounds.size, location: f.bounds.origin))
        }
```

and where the stars are created:

```
///Creates a star on a layer and puts it over the point passed in
    func createMarker(size: CGSize, location: CGPoint) -> CALayer{

        print("The marker will be at [\(location.x),\(location.y)]")
        //doesn't appear in correct place on the screen
        let newLayer = CALayer()
        newLayer.bounds = imageViewer.bounds
        newLayer.frame = CGRect(origin: location, size: size)
        newLayer.contents = UIImage(named: "star")?.CGImage
        newLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.0).CGColor
        newLayer.masksToBounds = false

        return newLayer
    }
```

Has anyone encountered anything like this before?

Comment: What is the UIViewContentMode of the image view?

Comment: Aspect Fit - my understanding is that this makes the images the same scale, but within the bounds of the UIImageView?

Comment: Makes it the same aspect ratio, not same scale. I would try top left for your code to work as is.

Comment: Cool thanks for the tip - I just tried it and this makes the picture size stay the same in some cases I can't see the whole image as it's larger than the width of the screen. This also still doesn't make the rectangles get detected.

Comment: @geeks_kick did you get to know how you can check if there are multiple rectangles in the image?

Comment: Please advise here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54399074/cidetector-not-detecting-proper-rectangle-in-ios

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think the rectangles you are using are compatible with the image you're using. If you look at the [CIDetector Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreImage/Reference/CIDetector_Ref/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Detector_Types) it reads:

> CIDetectorTypeRectangle A detector that searches for rectangular areas
> in a still image or video, returning CIRectangleFeature objects that
> provide information about detected regions.
>
> The rectangle detector finds areas that are likely to represent
> rectangular objects that appear in perspective in the image, such as
> papers or books seen on a desktop.

Taking this advice I ran your code on this image:[image]

With the results:

> bounds = "(296.752716064453, 74.7079086303711, 181.281158447266,
> 253.205474853516)\n"

I ran your code on other plan rectangles with no features found. Needs to be somewhat of a "real-world" image.