# Rectangle/Square Detection Swift

Tags: swift, rectangles

I am trying to find a way to detect rectangles and squares in an image:

[image]

The problem is I can't find really any way to do it. I have researched a CIDetector that can do this but it seems like that is more for "real world examples" and not for an image like the one I uploaded.

Comment: What's your issue with CoreImage? That's the right route to go.

Comment: I was looking at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34244752/cidetector-either-not-detecting-or-detecting-in-odd-places

Comment: Will CoreImage be able to detect the rectangle in an image like the one I have in the question? If so, then CoreImage is the obvious way to go in my mind.